# I'm trying to download and save an image from the web using python's requests module

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to download this image through requests by this url but idk certain error occurs at line 17 that don't define what's the problem.

I have tried adding the http:// with the url to make it a clear url.

here is the code that I have written.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'E:/Summer/FirstThings/Web scraping (bucky + pdf)/webscraping/tutorials-master/chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.nba.com/players/jaylen/adams/1629121'
driver.get(url)
#print(driver.page_source)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source , 'lxml')
div = soup.find('section' , class_='nba-player-header__item nba-player-header__headshot')
img = div.find('img')
print("")
m=('http://'+ img['src'])

f = open('jaylen_adams.jpg','w')
f.write(requests.get(m).content)
f.close()

driver.__exit__()
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

Couple errors I found:

first, you need to fix the url as it's trying to access `http:////ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/headshots/nba/latest/260x190/1629121.png` which is invalid. So change the line to:

```
m=('http:'+ img['src'])
```

Second, you need to write as bytes. so change to:

```
f = open('C:/jaylen_adams.jpg','wb')
```

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.nba.com/players/jaylen/adams/1629121'
driver.get(url)
#print(driver.page_source)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source , 'lxml')
div = soup.find('section' , class_='nba-player-header__item nba-player-header__headshot')
img = div.find('img')
print("")
m=('http:'+ img['src'])  # <----- edit made here

f = open('C:/jaylen_adams.jpg','wb')   # <---- edit made here
f.write(requests.get(m).content)
f.close()

driver.__exit__()
```

**ALSO:** There's no need to use selenium, as that might slow down the process if you're doing multiple pages. You could simplify it by just using requests, and also eliminate the need to use `.close()` the file if you you put it in a `with` statement, as it automatically will close after it finishes:

**Shorter Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.nba.com/players/jaylen/adams/1629121'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text , 'lxml')
div = soup.find('section' , class_='nba-player-header__item nba-player-header__headshot')
img = div.find('img')
print("")
m=('http:'+ img['src'])

with open('C:/jaylen_adams.jpg','wb') as f:
    f.write(requests.get(m).content)
```